# Providing half of the composite key 'manually', while the other half remains auto-generated

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity with a composite key

```
public class Transaction
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int AccountId { get; internal set; }
}
```

The following works fine:

```
var account = repo.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(...);
var transaction = new Transaction();
account.Transactions.Add(transaction);
repo.Save();
```

But I have a case where I want to set half of it - the `AccountId` to something, on Insert, while the other half (`Id`) is supposed to remain auto-generated. i.e.

```
// this doesn't work
var transaction = new Transaction();
transaction.AccountId = 125;
repo.Transactions.Add(transaction);
repo.Save();
```

So, I want to avoid retrieving the `Account` from the db, because I already know its `ID`.
I am getting

> A foreign key value cannot be inserted because a corresponding primary
>   key value does not exist error.

I have tested and if I set both of them to something, it will work. i.e.:

```
// this works
var transaction = new Transaction();
transaction.AccountId = 125;
transaction.Id = 1000;
repo.Transactions.Add(transaction);
repo.Save();
```

Is it somehow possible to set `AccountId` manually, while `Id` still auto-generates on database save?

Comment: Even if you get this to work, the fact that `Id` is an identity column means that it will be unique across all rows, so you could just as well make `Id` the key by itself. If you want `Id` to start from 1 for each `AccountId`, then you'll need to set the values manually: identity columns simply don't do that.

Comment: It is necessary `AccountId` to be part of the composite key, because when I delete the `Account` I want cascade delete to work for the collection of child objects too. Hm, or actually `[required] AccountId` on the child object might be enough to enforce this ...

Comment: It seems that the `AccountId` that you are trying to add doesn't exist in the parent table. (I guess `Account` table)

Comment: @OfirW - but it does :/ I think the issue is the `Id` column not provided by me, when I provide the other half of the key - `AccountId`.

Comment: @HristoYankov Yeah, cascaded deletes work even when the account ID is not part of the key. It might or might not be sufficient to mark it as required, but regardless, there are ways to explicitly mark it as requiring cascading deletes.

Comment: clarify the primary key and foreign key with fluent api, data annotation is confusing sometimes.

Comment: Show the code that causes the error and the essential parts of the classes that are involved. The description is too vague. I don't understand how you expect to be able to set only one half of a foreign key.

Comment: @GertArnold, the EF object is defined as in the posted code. The relevant part is that it has a composite key, where half the key (`Id`) is supposed to be auto-generated by EF (or sql, whatever), the other half is 'provided'. This works fine when during insert when the actual related entity (`Account`) is provided as part of the graph. However I have a situation where I don't want to provide the whole `Account`, but I know its ID. And I want to insert my object by providing half the key (`AccountId`), while the `Id` remains auto-generated. That's what causes the error, which is an EF error.

Comment: Try to imagine you're just a random reader seeing this question for the first time. Anyway, it's your call. All I know is that your scenario (what I can piece together from it) shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: @GertArnold, you are right. I have updated the question.

Comment: Well, `transaction.Id` isn't generated by the database, although you tell EF it is.